# Debug version of the code runs 10 times faster compared to released installed app

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, mysqldatareader

One of my functions run 10 times slower on the same computer when using the installed release version of the application compared to running the same code in the VS 2107 debug dialog mode. clearly the debug mode does something or pre-load something that helps the code to run faster, I can't figure out what is it ?

I tried to make the code more efficient but it doesn't help because the problem isn't related to the complexity of the code, it is actually simple.

```
 public void AcuSyncRegularProtocol(string DateStamp, string EnergyStart, string EnergyEnd, string tanentTable)
    {

        List<string> EnergyList = new List<string>();
        List<string> TableList = new List<string>();

        decimal EnergyStartValue = Convert.ToDecimal(EnergyStart);
        decimal EnergyEndValue = Convert.ToDecimal(EnergyEnd);
        decimal EnergyConsumed = EnergyEndValue - EnergyStartValue;
        decimal sharp = 0;
        decimal peack = 0;
        decimal valley = 0;

        string tou_type = "0";
        string tou_tariff = "0";
        string tou_schedule = "0";
        string tou_schedule_type = "0";
        string tou_schedule_number = "0";
        string time = "0";

        int index = -1;

        ConvertStringTime cst = new ConvertStringTime();
        DateTime DateInput = cst.ParseExactConverter(DateStamp);
        if (DateInput.Minute.ToString() == "0") { DateInput = DateInput.AddHours(-1); }

        //Get the correct TOU tables based on the date

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand CycleTableInfo = new MySqlCommand("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema ='acumanager';", myConn);

            MySqlDataReader CycleTableInfoReader;
            myConn.Open();
            CycleTableInfoReader = CycleTableInfo.ExecuteReader();
            while (CycleTableInfoReader.Read())
            {
                string tmp = CycleTableInfoReader.GetString("TABLE_NAME");

                //Get only TOU related tables

                if ((tmp.Contains("tou_") == true))
                {
                    DateTime StartTuoDate = cst.ParseExactConverter(tmp);

                    if (StartTuoDate <= DateInput)
                    {
                        TableList.Add(CycleTableInfoReader["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        //filter old unwanted tables

        for (int i = 0; i < TableList.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime CurrentTable = cst.ParseExactConverter(TableList[i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < TableList.Count; j++)
            {
                DateTime ReferenceTable = cst.ParseExactConverter(TableList[j]);

                if (ReferenceTable > CurrentTable) { TableList.RemoveAt(i); break; }

            }
        }

        //find the index of the seasons table

        for (int i = 0; i < TableList.Count; i++) { if (TableList[i].Contains("tou_seasons")) { index = i; break; } }

        //Get the correct schedule type based on the day of week

        tou_schedule_type = DateInput.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        if (tou_schedule_type == "Friday") { tou_schedule_type = "schedule-f"; }
        else if (tou_schedule_type == "Saturday") { tou_schedule_type = "schedule-s"; }
        else { tou_schedule_type = "schedule-w"; }

        //Get the schedule number based on schedule type and inputdate month

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand CycleTableInfo = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM acumanager.`" + TableList[index] + "` WHERE month ='" + DateInput.Month.ToString() + "'; ", myConn);

            MySqlDataReader CycleTableInfoReader;
            myConn.Open();
            CycleTableInfoReader = CycleTableInfo.ExecuteReader();
            while (CycleTableInfoReader.Read())
            {
                tou_schedule_number = CycleTableInfoReader.GetString(tou_schedule_type);
            }
            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        tou_schedule = "schedule" + tou_schedule_number;
        tou_tariff = "tariff" + tou_schedule_number;

        //find the index of the schedule table

        for (int i = 0; i < TableList.Count; i++) { if (TableList[i].Contains("tou_schedules")) { index = i; break; } }

        //Get the tariff based on schedule number and time

        time = DateInput.Hour.ToString() + ":00" + ":00";

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand CycleTableInfo = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM acumanager.`" + TableList[index] + "` WHERE " + tou_schedule + " ='" + time + "'; ", myConn);
            MySqlDataReader CycleTableInfoReader;
            myConn.Open();
            CycleTableInfoReader = CycleTableInfo.ExecuteReader();

            while (CycleTableInfoReader.Read())
            {
                tou_tariff = CycleTableInfoReader.GetString(tou_tariff);
            }
            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        //find the index of the price table

        for (int i = 0; i < TableList.Count; i++) { if (TableList[i].Contains("tou_prices")) { index = i; break; } }

        //Get the correct ennergy type base on the tariff

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand CycleTableInfo = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM acumanager.`" + TableList[index] + "` WHERE tou_price_id ='" + tou_tariff + "'; ", myConn);

            MySqlDataReader CycleTableInfoReader;
            myConn.Open();
            CycleTableInfoReader = CycleTableInfo.ExecuteReader();

            while (CycleTableInfoReader.Read())
            {
                tou_type = CycleTableInfoReader.GetString("nameENG");
            }
            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        //Get the previous values of TOU

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand InsertEntry = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM customers." + tanentTable + " ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1;", myConn);
            MySqlDataReader CycleTableInfoReader;
            myConn.Open();
            CycleTableInfoReader = InsertEntry.ExecuteReader();
            while (CycleTableInfoReader.Read())
            {
                sharp = CycleTableInfoReader.GetDecimal("Sharp");
                peack = CycleTableInfoReader.GetDecimal("Peack");
                valley = CycleTableInfoReader.GetDecimal("Valley");
            }
            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); myConn.Close(); }
        myConn.Close();

        //add the delta to the correct TOU type

        if (tou_type == "Sharp") { sharp = sharp + EnergyConsumed; }
        else if (tou_type == "Peack") { peack = peack + EnergyConsumed; }
        else if (tou_type == "Valley") { valley = valley + EnergyConsumed; }
        else { MessageBox.Show("תקלה בזיהוי התעריף"); }

        //insert the TOU values back

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand InsertEntry = new MySqlCommand("insert into customers." + tanentTable + " (Date,Energy,Sharp,Peack,Valley) values('" + DateStamp + "','" + EnergyEnd + "','" + sharp + "', '" + peack + "', '" + valley + "')  ;", myConn);
            MySqlDataReader CycleTableInfoReader;
            myConn.Open();
            CycleTableInfoReader = InsertEntry.ExecuteReader();
            myConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.ToString().Contains("Duplicate entry") == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                myConn.Close();
            }
        }
        myConn.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Chances are then your code is fighting amongst itself and causing its self to wait.. but without code its hard to tell

Comment: "The code it self isn't relevant to the problem" - that seems vanishingly unlikely

Comment: On the off-chance: is it possible that you have manually inverted the "Optimize code" checkbox in the project settings, such that it is optimized in debug and not optimized in release? And have you checked the other project settings between debug/release? Are you running with the debugger attached in either case? (for a performance overview, you don't want to do that - you want to run the exe completely isolated from the IDE)

Comment: You still have to show some code, so others can get idea what is happening and how possibly debug environment can affect it. Tagging with `[mysqldatareader]` and `[winforms]` is not enough. Try to reinstall framework, huh?

Comment: I added the code, there are no errors and it runs fast on debug, slow on release.

Comment: Execution speed of this code is entirely dominated by the efficiency of the dbase engine, it has nothing to do with the code itself.  That engine doesn't give a hoot about the flavor of the build.  The usual reason for a slow final version is that you now expose it to real data instead of test data or use a dbase that is no longer local to the machine.

Comment: Thank you Hans , that is why I said the code isn't relevant but the problem is that I compared it with " real data" on the same computer, the difference was running the same code via VS 2017 debug compared to regular execution via the .exe file, the dbase is local on both cases.

Comment: Try the .exe in the Debug folder and compare it to the performance of the .exe in the Release folder.

Comment: A performance profiler should reveal where the extra time goes. Without that it is difficult to guess what might be wrong.